# Make the value as 0, if rows not available in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

My query has count function which returns the count of rows summarized by day. Now, when there are no rows from that table, I'm not getting any result, instead I need, rows with all days and count as zero. I tried with `coalesc` but didnt work. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Here is my query:

```
exceptions
 | where name == 'my_scheduler' and timestamp > ago(30d)
 | extend day = split(tostring(timestamp + 19800s), 'T')[0]
 | summarize schedulerFailed = coalesce(count(),tolong("0")) by tostring(day)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of [`summarize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) you need to use [`make-series`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator) which will fill the gaps with a default value for you.

```
exceptions
| where name == 'my_scheduler' and timestamp > ago(30d)
| extend day = split(tostring(timestamp + 19800s), 'T')[0]
| make-series count() on tolong(x) step 1
```

You might want to add `from` and `to` to `make-series` in order for it to also fill gaps at the beginning and the end of the 30d period.

Comment: Thank you. WIll use this

Comment: Glad to help. Will appreciate if you accept the answer, by clicking on the "V" :)  Thanks!